# What do you call a minor triad with a 4th in the bass?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, chord-inversions

Is this chord still a minor triad if you use a 4th in the bass or does the chord change? Can anyone think of any examples in pop or rock music where this is used?

thank you

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "4th" in the bass? Do you mean it's in second inversion?

Comment: So a minor chord with a 4th of the minor scale in the bass. For example, Aminor with a D in the bass.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see three distinct possibilities based on how you are actually thinking about the chord itself:

- If you really just consider it an A minor chord, it might just end up being a slash chord with a non harmonic tone in the bass. So it would be **Am/D**.
- I would most likely name it **D7sus2** which is spelled `D E A C`. This makes most sense to me since there's no third, but a there is a 2nd/9th present which make sense for the sus.
- Another possibility is if you want to look at all the notes together as one unit then I'd view this as an inverted **C6/9** chord which is spelled `C E (G) A D`. The G is not there, but omitting the 5th is quite common in actually playing chords which will show more of the quartal/quintal nature of the notes themselves, but is a streach naming wise.

Answer (score 1):

I agree 100% with what Dom said, I just wanted to add that identifying a chords name often requires looking at its siblings and/or the key the piece is written in. Taking your example with A- and D in the bass I would interpret it as either

- D7sus2: `D E (F#) A C`
- D-7sus2: `D E (F) A C`

because of the D in the bass. Not applicable to rootless voicings of course.

Comment: Thirds are omitted in sus chords, so those two chords look like **D9** and **D-9**.

Comment: Correct, they are omitted, but if your piece is written in e.g. D-Minor, as a purist you would call the chord D-7sus2 to outline the omitted diatonic third.

Comment: That really makes no sense. If a third is part of the chord, it is not a sus chord. **D-7(sus2)** is not a purist notation, it is a confusing and not very common notation. The only times I have seen this used it was either attempting to communicate that the sus chord was based on a minor chord (usually unnecessary), or it was used incorrectly to name an extended 7th chord. In any case, I don't see why this is in an answer to _this_ question.

Comment: @DavidBowling, I don't think it's illogical. A sus chord omits a major or a minor third. D7sus would imply resolution to a major third, but D–7sus would imply resolution to a minor third. Communicating which is intended gives helpful information to, e.g., a soloist who is likely to play the third when improvising over the sus chord.

Comment: @jdjazz -- but sus chords don't contain 3rds, so this adds information that is irrelevant to the actual chord name; you can easily see what the chord movement is by looking at the next chord.

Comment: @DavidBowling, chords do more than just tell the comping instrument what notes to play. They communicate harmonic information to the soloist. There are many scenarios where one can't simply look at the next chord to find the resolution. In jazz, it's not uncommon, for example, to have consecutive sus chords moving up/down half steps, thirds, etc. If a composer wants the soloist to use the minor third over the major third, D–7sus would be the perfect way to communicate this.

Comment: @jdjazz -- if you have a series of sus chords following each other, it isn't immediately obvious to me how **C-7(sus4)** would convey useful information. If the melody contains a minor third here, maybe. When I improvise over changes, I always at least scope out the chords and the melody first; if there is no melody to see but only changes, this might be helpful. But these are somewhat special circumstances. My original point was that the note collections in this answer are 9th chords, not sus chords. This at least deserves some comment in the answer, I believe. But this all may be OOB the OP

Comment: @DavidBowling it's a way for the composer to tell the soloist, "if you're going to make your lines resolve, then resolve to the minor third not the major third." Also, Keith Jarrett and Brad Mehldau (probably others too) will sometimes voice a sus chord with the major third as a tension/non-chord tone. I recall Keith putting the major third in a really high register. Brad will pretty frequently voice the chord with the major third and fourth a half step apart in the mid register. Writing D-7(sus4) tells the comping instrument which third to use as a non-chord tone if they're going that route.

Comment: @jdjazz - usually, when improvising, I'll have a pretty shrewd idea as to whether a sus chord relates more strongly to a maj or min if the third was to be there, looking at its context. Don't think, in most cases, that it's necessary to be that precise, and I often will use a third (of either persuasion) in a sus bar. But including the third as well as a 'sus' in a chord makes it definitely an 'add 9' or 'add 11'.   When comping, again, I should know if the 'original' chord would have been maj or min., and if it's written as sus, that's surely what is required, without the third there - unless

Comment: the writer meant add something, in which case, it ought to be put in.